# Header() in php not working

Tags: php, web

I have developed a php web app which makes use of the `header()` function of `PHP`. For instance, when a user is logged in, the website should redirect to homepage. This works perfectly while testing the site on my local computer using `xampp` server , but when I try to access the site using its domain name, it does not redirect to homepage .

This is the code I have used :

```
$query = "select * from user where email= '$email' and pass= '$pass'";
$result = mysql_query($query);

if(mysql_num_rows($result) != 0) {
       $row = mysql_fetch_row($result);
       $_SESSION['user'] = $row[0];
       $_SESSION['email'] = $row[1];
       $_SESSION['pass'] = $row[2];
       $_SESSION['id'] = $row[3];
       $_SESSION['last_name'] = $row[4];
       $_SESSION['dp'] = $row[5];

       header("Location: index.php");
} else
    $wrong_cred = true;
}

if($wrong_cred) {
    echo("<div class='pageBegin'><p><h1>Wrong User name or Password></h1></p></div>");
}
```

Comment: And "does not work" means _what_ exactly? Nothing happens? Do you get an error or warning? Something wrong happens? Does the universe implode?

Comment: mysql_* is deprecated  and has been removed as of PHP 7.0.0. may be your server have higher version of php ..so enable your errors or check in logs and i m sure you got error of mysql_* function

Comment: Oh, and by the way: you _never_ store user passwords in a database. Never. What you store is a _hash of a user password_. Then at authentication time you again _hash_ the provided password and _compare the two hashes_. That way you don't compromise your users password even if your server gets hacked.

Comment: I come back after ages and they're still using the deprecated mysql_* functions.

Comment: @user5173426 That's because reading the documentation is regarded as "uncool", "boring" or "not really necessary" by many... (sigh)

Comment: @arkascha hah, too many I-can-do-it-my-way out there! `;-)`

Comment: @user5173426 No, actually I found out that many beginenrs are not aware that there is a documentation. They think some code snippets and "beginners tutorial" are "the documentation". No idea why.

Comment: @arkascha it uses sha256 hash. the variable $pass stores the sha256 hash value of the password entered by the user . And regarding the use of deprecated mysql_* functions , yes my knowledge of php is dated and I'm not a full time web developer. I had to work on this website and had no time to update my knowledge of php and mysql.

Comment: OK, all fine, sounds like you know what you have to take care of. Good luck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `@obstart` or try to use Java Script

put your `obstart();` into your top of the page

```
if ((isset($_POST['cancel'])) && ($_POST['cancel'] == 'cancel'))
{
    header('Location: page1.php');
    exit();
}
```

If you use Javascript Use  window.location.href

window.location.href example:

```
 if ((isset($_POST['cancel'])) && ($_POST['cancel'] == 'cancel'))
    {
        echo "<script type='text/javascript'>window.location.href = 'page1.php';</script>"
        exit();
    }
```

Comment: Nice to see someone actually trying to help a beginner rather than bashing :) . thanks